# GUI toolkit for creating fully customized UIs? If I were going for a completely non-os native look, which toolkit would you suggest?

Tags: python, user-interface

I've been asked to build a gui for a friend. We're going for a fully custom look. All buttons, states, widgets, etc.. will be will be drawn by an artist. The only native widget I foresee needing is a listbox (because I'm not entirely sure how I would build one from scratch).

Additional requirements are mp3 playback support.

The list of available frameworks on python.org is pretty daunting! Could anyone suggest a good starting point?

I apologize for the open ended-ness of the question!

Comment: You're unlikely to find MP3 support in a GUI library. That should be handled by a sound playing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build it with [pygame](http://www.pygame.org) would be my advice.

That will give you a pixel identical GUI on all platforms - ideal if you have an artist make everything for you.

You'll have to implement your own listbox, but pygame plays mp3s just fine.